# How to create mongo container with my python app container inside same pod in kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I want to migrate my in kubernetes cluster and created my own clusters manually. I have made an app in python and connect it with mongoDB using the official mongo image mongo. it works fine in docker compose because after creating container i manual enters the mongo container and make replicaSet and user of my choice after my service start working. but when i shift my service to kubernetes deployment and make 2 or 3 replicas of deployment then i have to initialise mongo by doing to every pod one by is there any way to automate the mongnoDB container that can automatically set the user name and password and replicaSet as well.

Comment: You'd almost always create MongoDB in a separate StatefulSet – you don't want to stop and replace your database every time you have a new version of your application.  Any workflow that involves "manually enter" pods won't run well in Kubernetes, where you frequently have multiple pods and they can be recreated automatically in some cases.  What have you done so far, and is there a specific problem you're running into?

Comment: i am running main database separately but in pod i want to run temporary database for some processing and after that put the results back to main db so i have to put this temporary  mongodb inside the same pod in which my service container is running i cannot run it separately because replicaset will have its own temporary database